# Modify all the lines of a dataframe according to a condition, this dataframe being itself an element of a list

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of 2 elements whose second is a dataframe.
I want to replace for all values ​​of one of the columns of the dataframe, if a condition is met
[image: list content]
the variable whose values ​​are to be changed is called "CODE_PAYS_LIV"

If the value in column "CODE_PAYS_LIV"  belongs to an element of the following list :
c("AT","BE" , "CH" , "CZ" , "DE" , "DK" ,"ES" , "FR" , "GB" , "HR" , "HU" , "IE" ,
"IT" , "NL" , "NO" , "PL" , "PT" , "SE" , "SI" , "SK"))

it have to be change to "EUR"

I have tried making these changes two different ways (without success)
directly calling a function, or using lapply to apply the function

I started by defining a function that tests if the condition is true

```
modif_res_veh <-function(fichier_veh) {

       ii<-1 

       nb_mesh <- nrow(fichier_veh)

      for (ii in 1:nb_mesh) {

           if (fichier_veh$CODE_PAYS_LIV %in% c("AT","BE" , "CH" , "CZ" , "DE" , "DK" , "ES" , "FR"))                                 
                   {fichier_veh$CODE_PAYS_LIV <- "EUR" }

       }
}
```

and then I have tried ti call this function

<> First test by using :
Res_vehicule [[2]] <- modif_res_veh(Res_vehicule [[2]])

```
  this gives me a list of 1 empty element
```

<> second test  by using :

Res_vehicule <- lapply(Res_vehicule[[2]] ,modif_res_veh)

```
  but i have this error message :
```

Error in 1:nb_mesh : argument of length 0

<> third test by passing the number of rows of the dataframe as a parameter of the function :

```
modif_res_veh <-function(fichier_veh, nb_mesh) {

       ii<-1 

      for (ii in 1:nb_mesh) {

           if (fichier_veh$CODE_PAYS_LIV %in% c("AT","BE" , "CH" , "CZ" , "DE" , "DK" , "ES" , "FR"))                                 
                   {fichier_veh$CODE_PAYS_LIV <- "EUR" }

       }
}

     nb_mesh <- nrow(Res_vehicule [[2]]) 

    Res_vehicule [[2]] <- modif_res_veh(Res_vehicule [[2]],nb_mesh)


but this gives me a list of 1 empty element again
```

thank you very much for your help

Comment: your function `modif_res_veh` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

one option:

```
flag_EU_members <- function(country_vector){
    ifelse(
        country_vector %in% c("AT", "BE", "CH"), ## etc.
        'EUR',
        country_vector
    )
}

Res_vehicule[[2]]$CODE_PAYS_LIV <-
    flag_EU_members(Res_vehicule[[2]]$CODE_PAYS_LIV)
```